# multiple panel in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

Is it possible to have multiple panel in wxpython? I want to have something like this:

```
import wx.grid
import sys

class Mat_Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self,wx.GetApp().TopWindow,title='Material Properties')
        self.panel=wx.Panel(self,-1)
        self.AdderPanel=wx.Panel(self.panel,-1)
        self.InputPanel=wx.Panel(self.panel,-1)
        self.OutputPanel=wx.Panel(self.panel,-1)
        HorSizer=wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        HorSizer.Add(self.panel,proportion=1,flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)
        HorSizer.Add(self.AdderPanel,proportion=1,flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)
        HorSizer.Add(self.InputPanel,proportion=1,flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)
        HorSizer.Add(self.OutputPanel,proportion=1,flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)
```

I tried this but it is not working. I mean, I get weird window unsized properly. Am I doing something wrong here? Can somebody point me how to use multiple panels in wxpython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I just realized I had forgotten to set the sizer. It worked fine after that.

Answer (score 1):

You can create as many Panels as you want.  You've only created one though, then a series of tuples.  You may want this:

```
self.panel=wx.Panel(self,-1,size=(x,x))
panel1=wx.Panel(self.panel,-1,size=(x,x))
panel2=wx.Panel(self.panel,-1,size=(x,x))
```

That will actually create several Panels, with the second two being children of the first one.  Their layout isn't going to be friendly yet though - you're going to need to look into Sizers.

Comment: Sorry for the typo before. I had done what you suggested but the output is not sized properly when I used sizers. Can you please take a look and see me mistake.