# Graphics issue upon resizing a panel in wxPython

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, wxpython

I am working with python v2.7 and wxPython v3.0 on Windows 8 OS.
*(Sorry for the confusing title. I have no idea what the title should be. I shall try my best to explain my problem in detail.)*

In my app I have a scrolled panel with a background image. This panel is named as `mainPanel` in the code snippet. This `mainPanel`contains other panels named as `myPanelA` and `myPanelB` that have transparent background. These panels `myPanelA` and `myPanelB` contains sizers that are containing some buttons. *PS: This is just a sample of my real world app. In my real world app I have many different panels and buttons. In this case the patches are more big and annoying.* :(

**Problem**: When I resize my windows horizontally, some times *(In my real world app it is very frequent as compared to this sample app.)* I see blank patches in my App windows as shown in sample images below. How can I avoid this? *It would be great if some one can test this and report if they have same problem on their machine (Just to be sure this is not Windows OS issue. I tested on Windows 7 too, it has the same problem.)*

**Update:** Simply resize the window and scroll vertically, you'll see the patches quite often.

**Sample Images**: The patch is pointed by an arrow.
[image: example1]
[image: example2]
[image: example3]

**Code:** Here is my code sample for playing around. The background image can be downloaded from here. [greensquares.jpg](https://db.tt/SKMw8Dlm)

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel

class gui(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, id, title, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
        mainPanel = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self, -1)
        mainPanel.SetupScrolling()
        myImage = wx.Image('greensquares.jpg', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        myBitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(mainPanel, -1, myImage, (0, 0))
        myPanelA = wx.Panel(myBitmap, -1, style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, pos=(100,0), size=(150,150))
        wx.StaticText(myPanelA, -1, '     MyPanelA    ')
        myButton1A = wx.Button(myPanelA, -1, size=(20,20))
        myButton2A = wx.Button(myPanelA, -1, size=(20,20))
        mySizerA = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        mySizerA.Add(myButton1A, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        mySizerA.Add(myButton2A, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        myPanelA.SetSizer(mySizerA)
        myPanelA.Layout()

        myPanelB = wx.Panel(myBitmap, -1, style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, pos=(100,130), size=(250,200))
        wx.StaticText(myPanelB, -1, '      MyPanelB    ')
        myButton1B = wx.Button(myPanelB, -1, size=(20,20))
        myButton2B = wx.Button(myPanelB, -1, size=(20,20))
        myButton3B = wx.Button(myPanelB, -1, size=(20,20))
        myButton4B = wx.Button(myPanelB, -1, size=(20,20))
        mySizerB1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        mySizerB1.Add(myButton1B, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        mySizerB1.Add(myButton2B, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        mySizerB1.Add(myButton3B, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        mySizerB1.Add(myButton4B, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        myButton5B = wx.Button(myPanelB, -1, size=(20,20))
        myButton6B = wx.Button(myPanelB, -1, size=(20,20))
        myButton7B = wx.Button(myPanelB, -1, size=(20,20))
        myButton8B = wx.Button(myPanelB, -1, size=(20,20))
        mySizerB2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        mySizerB2.Add(myButton5B, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        mySizerB2.Add(myButton6B, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        mySizerB2.Add(myButton7B, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        mySizerB2.Add(myButton8B, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        mySizerC = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        mySizerC.Add(mySizerB1)
        mySizerC.Add(mySizerB2)
        myPanelB.SetSizer(mySizerC)
        myPanelB.Layout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = gui(parent=None, id=-1, title="My-App")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. In addition to what [multiphrenic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23117706/2382792) has suggested I have also binded the scroll event to a the `OnResize()`. So, that when ever any scroll event [EVT_SCROLL](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ScrollEvent-class.html)  occurs the panels will be updated too. It is working fine on Windows7, 8 OS with python v2.7 and wxPython v3.0.

**Working code:**

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel

class gui(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, id, title, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
        mainPanel = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self, -1)
        mainPanel.SetupScrolling()
        myImage = wx.Image('greensquares.jpg', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        myBitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(mainPanel, -1, myImage, (0, 0))
        self.myPanelA = wx.Panel(myBitmap, -1, style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, pos=(100,0), size=(150,150))
        wx.StaticText(self.myPanelA, -1, 'self.myPanelA')
        myButton1A = wx.Button(self.myPanelA, -1, size=(20,20))
        myButton2A = wx.Button(self.myPanelA, -1, size=(20,20))
        mySizerA = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        mySizerA.Add(myButton1A, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        mySizerA.Add(myButton2A, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        self.myPanelA.SetSizer(mySizerA)
        self.myPanelA.Layout()

        self.myPanelB = wx.Panel(myBitmap, -1, style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, pos=(100,130), size=(250,200))
        wx.StaticText(self.myPanelB, -1, 'self.myPanelB')
        myButton1B = wx.Button(self.myPanelB, -1, size=(20,20))
        myButton2B = wx.Button(self.myPanelB, -1, size=(20,20))
        myButton3B = wx.Button(self.myPanelB, -1, size=(20,20))
        myButton4B = wx.Button(self.myPanelB, -1, size=(20,20))
        mySizerB1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        mySizerB1.Add(myButton1B, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        mySizerB1.Add(myButton2B, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        mySizerB1.Add(myButton3B, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        mySizerB1.Add(myButton4B, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        myButton5B = wx.Button(self.myPanelB, -1, size=(20,20))
        myButton6B = wx.Button(self.myPanelB, -1, size=(20,20))
        myButton7B = wx.Button(self.myPanelB, -1, size=(20,20))
        myButton8B = wx.Button(self.myPanelB, -1, size=(20,20))
        mySizerB2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        mySizerB2.Add(myButton5B, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        mySizerB2.Add(myButton6B, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        mySizerB2.Add(myButton7B, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        mySizerB2.Add(myButton8B, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        mySizerC = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        mySizerC.Add(mySizerB1)
        mySizerC.Add(mySizerB2)
        self.myPanelB.SetSizer(mySizerC)
        self.myPanelB.Layout()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnResize)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLL, self.OnResize)

    def OnResize(self, e):
        self.myPanelA.Update()
        self.myPanelB.Update()
        e.Skip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = gui(parent=None, id=-1, title="My-App")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a Update method to your panels, which seems to have fixed the issue on my side.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel

class gui(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, id, title, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
        mainPanel = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self, -1)
        mainPanel.SetupScrolling()
        myImage = wx.Image('greensquares.jpg', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        myBitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(mainPanel, -1, myImage, (0, 0))
        self.myPanelA = wx.Panel(myBitmap, -1, style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, pos=(100,0), size=(150,150))
        wx.StaticText(self.myPanelA, -1, '     self.myPanelA    ')
        myButton1A = wx.Button(self.myPanelA, -1, size=(20,20))
        myButton2A = wx.Button(self.myPanelA, -1, size=(20,20))
        mySizerA = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        mySizerA.Add(myButton1A, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        mySizerA.Add(myButton2A, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        self.myPanelA.SetSizer(mySizerA)
        self.myPanelA.Layout()

        self.myPanelB = wx.Panel(myBitmap, -1, style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, pos=(100,130), size=(250,200))
        wx.StaticText(self.myPanelB, -1, '      self.myPanelB    ')
        myButton1B = wx.Button(self.myPanelB, -1, size=(20,20))
        myButton2B = wx.Button(self.myPanelB, -1, size=(20,20))
        myButton3B = wx.Button(self.myPanelB, -1, size=(20,20))
        myButton4B = wx.Button(self.myPanelB, -1, size=(20,20))
        mySizerB1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        mySizerB1.Add(myButton1B, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        mySizerB1.Add(myButton2B, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        mySizerB1.Add(myButton3B, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        mySizerB1.Add(myButton4B, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        myButton5B = wx.Button(self.myPanelB, -1, size=(20,20))
        myButton6B = wx.Button(self.myPanelB, -1, size=(20,20))
        myButton7B = wx.Button(self.myPanelB, -1, size=(20,20))
        myButton8B = wx.Button(self.myPanelB, -1, size=(20,20))
        mySizerB2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        mySizerB2.Add(myButton5B, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        mySizerB2.Add(myButton6B, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        mySizerB2.Add(myButton7B, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        mySizerB2.Add(myButton8B, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        mySizerC = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        mySizerC.Add(mySizerB1)
        mySizerC.Add(mySizerB2)
        self.myPanelB.SetSizer(mySizerC)
        self.myPanelB.Layout()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnResize)

    def OnResize(self, e):
        self.myPanelA.Update()
        self.myPanelB.Update()
        e.Skip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = gui(parent=None, id=-1, title="My-App")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: First, Please do add the information regarding where you have tested your code! Second: Nothing has changed on Windows 8, wxPython v3.0 and python v2.7. Resize the panel and then scroll vertically. You may see the patches. :(

Comment: I tested the code on Windows XP, wxPython 2.8.5 and Python 2.7. I did not see any patches during the scroll in my test. I'll try when I get home to see if I have the same issue on newer hardware.